# How to display an image in HTML from Restful java

Tags: java, html, mongodb, web-services, rest

This method used to download an image by the imageID from MongoDB but I need to display an image in the HTML when the user request the URL. 
http://localhost:8080/UploadRest/webresources/files/download/file/64165

```
<img src="http://localhost:8080/UploadRest/webresources/files/download/file/64165">
```

**I need to make method display not download**

```
@GET
@Path("/download/file/{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response downloadFilebyID(@PathParam("id")  String id) throws IOException {

    Response response = null;
    MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI(CONNECTION_URL);
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);

    DB mongoDB = mongoClient.getDB(DATABASE_NAME);

    //Let's store the standard data in regular collection
    DBCollection collection = mongoDB.getCollection(USER_COLLECION);

    logger.info("Inside downloadFilebyID...");
    logger.info("ID: " + id);

    BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject();
    query.put("_id", id);
    DBObject doc = collection.findOne(query);
    DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query);

    if (cursor.hasNext()) {
        Set<String> allKeys = doc.keySet();
        HashMap<String, String> fields = new HashMap<String,String>();
        for (String key: allKeys) {
            fields.put(key, doc.get(key).toString());
        }

        logger.info("description: " + fields.get("description"));
        logger.info("department: " + fields.get("department"));
        logger.info("file_year: " + fields.get("file_year"));
        logger.info("filename: " + fields.get("filename"));

        GridFS fileStore = new GridFS(mongoDB, "filestore");
        GridFSDBFile gridFile = fileStore.findOne(query);

        InputStream in = gridFile.getInputStream();

        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int data = in.read();
        while (data >= 0) {
            out.write((char) data);
            data = in.read();
        }
        out.flush();

        ResponseBuilder builder = Response.ok(out.toByteArray());
        builder.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fields.get("filename"));
        response = builder.build();
    } else {
        response = Response.status(404).
        entity(" Unable to get file with ID: " + id).
        type("text/plain").
        build();
    }
    return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the line

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
```

This tells the client that you are returning an octet stream, i.e. a stream of bytes rather than an image. Depending on the file type of the image, you should produce the content type `image/png`, `image/jpeg` or whatever.

Since file types may vary at runtime, you cannot simply annotate `@Produces` here [1]. So you have to manually set the content type while constructing the `Response` object like this:

```
Response.ok(bytes, "image/png");
```

In your case you should store the media type alongside the filename in the database. Another possibility would be to implement a mapping of file extension to media type but storing the media type is more flexible and less error prone.

[1] Anyway you should only do this when there is a good reason to do so; in contrast to what is shown in many REST tutorials, you should omit the `@Produces` in most of the cases. The container can then produce the media type which was requested by the client.

Comment: thanks for your help , but can you give complete source cause i trying to do your answer and it give me exception